# Why Can I Not Use this Entity Framework Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created a SQL Stored Procedure and have added it the the Entity Framework.  However I am not able to reference  it using  something like this

List<My_StoredProcedure> results = db.My_StoredProcedure.ToList();  The stored procedure seems to not even exist.  I checked the data model and I see it in the list but it has a different icon.  All my tables and views have a wrench icon but the stored procedure has a cube icon.

I have searched for an answerer but only find old posts that talk about using a function import.  Those examples seem to be out of date.  Can someone please explain how I can accomplish this?

Comment: You may not have the credentials to run the stored procedure.  See following to add stored procedure to Entity : https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: In the intellisense popup a "cube icon"indicates a method; you have to follow a method name with `(` - you can't omit them in c# like you can in vb/with properties

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was my Stored Procedure was not returning a table.  So Entity Framework was treating like a method.  Had to redo the Stored Procedure to return a table.